# Force https for main domain and http for all subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to use my site's .htaccess file to rewrite all URLs for the main domain to force HTTPS, while all URLs on any subdomain should be forced to use HTTP.

Currently I have the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=([a-z0-9-]+).domain.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

This forces HTTPS on the main domain (https://domain.com) as well as any subdomains. I think I'm a little messed up on the third line, but just can't quite figure out what needs to go there.

Additionally, I'm thinking the third line will only exclude the subdomain from the rewrite rule to HTTPS, but if someone clicks on a link or types in https://sub.domain.com, they might still get through and end up with insecure content warnings. Perhaps there needs to be another condition in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A condition in the form of `RewriteCond variable =string` will compare the variable to the lexigraphical string (or in other words: the string as-is), not a regex. Presumably `RewriteCond variable !=string` would mean not that string.

You want to compare to a regex instead for the second rule. The first rule is simple, as we know the entire domain already.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =domain.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.+\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Change the `R` flag to `R=301` once you have tested that everything works as expected.

I believe when the user goes to `https://sub.domain.com`, it will still generate security warnings. This is because the browser will not complete the handshake if the certificate is invalid. It will instead prompt the user that the connection might be hijacked and gives the user the option to continue. If the user continues the user is redirected, and no security warnings are displayed. **Make sure there are no https-links to your sub-domains anywhere!**

Comment: I have edited in some more information about a https-to-http-redirect.

Comment: I was hoping to be able to avoid the security warnings you mentioned, but I'm looking at my site and there are no links directly to the subdomains with https in them, so the only way someone would get there that way would be if they manually typed in `https://sub.domain.com`, at which point it's their problem for doing that. Thanks!

Comment: If I want to do the opposite, that is force a sub.domain.com to https but NOT the force the main domain to https can I just flip these?

Comment: Yes. The first rule explicitly only matches the domain without a subdomain (so not even www), and the second rule matches all sub domains (including www). It should work fine if you used `%{HTTPS} on` in the first rule and `%{HTTPS} off` in the second.